# Will this huge javascript array loaded from a database crash my website?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

So on this website I'm making (who knows if i'll actually finish it lol) when someone opens up the new user page, php echos into a javascript script all the usernames from the database to create an array.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var allUsers = ['!' <?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users ")  or die("error " .mysql_error());
        $usersArray = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $usersArray[] = $row['username'] or die("error ". mysql_error()); 
            }

            foreach ($usersArray as $name) {
                echo ',' . json_encode($name );
            }

         ?> , ];
```

the point of this is to have a live checker so if you type in a username that already exists, red text shows up next to the username input. But let's say I get 1,000,000 users (completely theoretical). Fortunately, the array only gets created at the beginning of the web page load. But will the function that checks if the username already exists in the huge array and gets called everytime someone changes the text in the username input put too much stress on the script and crash the website? If so, is there a better way to do what I'm describing?

Here's the rest of the code

```
function contains(a, obj) {
   var i = a.length;
   while (i--) {
   if (a[i] === obj) {
   return true;
   }
   }
   return false;
   }


   function onUserChange() { //gets called onkeypress, onpaste, and oninput
               if(contains(allUsers, str)) {
               div.innerHTML = "Username already exists";
               div.style.color = "red";
               userValid = false;
               }
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: That seems extremely inefficient, and provides a list of all your usernames to anyone who wants to hack your script (probably very easy). Why not use a request onblur or similar and check the name at the backend?

Comment: it would be better to send the username to the server (through ajax) have it do a mysql query to see if the username is already taken and respond back with message saying wither or not it is taken.

Comment: @PatrickEvans—snap! Every second counts… ;-)

Comment: if your going to use key press i suggest using a self overwriting timeout function that way you give the use a few seconds after pressing to check, you'll also want to probably abort the ajax call if one is already in progress..

Comment: @PatrickEvans you can go ahead and put it as an answer if you want

Comment: To echo above conmments, doing this client side is a terrible idea.  Honestly you shouldn't really even give indication that a username exists or not, as this is bas security practice"

Comment: @RobG Now i feel extremly stupid haha

Comment: @RobG, That it does, and now i have the "Every little thing counts" song stuck in my head

Comment: 10,000 is pushing it client side, 1,000,000 is unreasonable.

Comment: @MikeBrant I assume your saying that you shouldn't indicate the username exists until the user clicks the submit button... you'd have to tell them at some point because you can't have duplicate usernames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines. ( with jQuery and PDO ) - note - code is not tested.

```
var keyTimer, request;

$('namefield').blur(function(){
   onUserChange();
});


$('namefield').keyup(function(){
   onUserChange();
});

function onUserChange() { //gets called onkeypress, onblur
    keyTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        if(request && request.readystate != 4){
            //cancel a previous request if a new request is made.
            request.abort();
        }
         request = $.post(
                           'http://yoursite.com/location/of/username/script.php', //post data to server
                            {username : $('namefield').val()},
                            function(data){
                               if(data == 0 ) { //might be a string here
                                    alert( 'the name is ok to use.' );
                               }else{
                                   alert( 'someone has this name already.' );
                                }
                            }
                   );

     }, 500); //overwrite previous timeout if user hits key within 500 milliseconds
   }
```

Then in the backend

```
    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username'; 
    //insert from post username but we are good programers and are using PDO to prevent sql injection.
    //search for the username in the db, count the number of users or rows should be 1 someone has it 0 no one has it assuming its unique.
$stmt = $Pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':username', $_POST['username']));
echo $stmt->rowCount();
exit();
```

etc.....

Answer (score 0):

Do not do it. My counsel is to use ajax to load the php file that will make a query asking only for the user that was typed in the input and retunr only a boolean value(exists=true / notexists=false)

Code example:

HTML(yourFile.html):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   //When the value inside the input changes fire this ajax querying the php file:
   jQuery("#inputUser").change(function(){
       var input = jQuery(this);
       jQuery.ajax({
          type:"post",
          url:"path/to/file.php",
          data:input.val(),
          success: function(data){
              //if php returns true, adds a red error message
              if(data == "1"){
                  input.after('<small style="color:#ff0000;">This username already exists</small>');
              //if php returns false, adds a green success message
              } else if(data == "0"){
                  input.after('<small style="color:#00ff00;">You can use this username</small>');
              }

          }
       });

   });
});
</script>
<input id="inputUser" type="text" name="username" value="">
```

PHP(path/to/file.php):

```
<?php
$username = $_REQUEST['username']; // The value from the input
$res = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'"); // asking only for the username inserted
$resArr = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

//verify if the result array from mysql query is empty.(if yes, returns false, else, returns true)
if(empty($resArr)){
    echo false;
} else{
    echo true;
}
```

?>

Comment: -could you please update this for proper modern day, sql, ie. the kind that cant get sql injection attacks done to it.

Answer (score -1):

As I can see you need to load the PHP code when your website is loading. 
First, I recommend you to separate the code. The fact that you can mix Javascript with PHP doesn't mean it is the best practice.

Second, yes, it's not efficient your code since you make Javascript load the result so you can search into it next. What I suggest you is making the search in the server side, not in client side, because as you say, if you have 100 elements maybe the best is to load all the content and execute the function, but if you have 1,000,000 elements maybe the best is to leave the server to compute so it can make the query with SQL.

Third, you can do all this using Ajax, using Javascript or using a framework like jQuery so you don't have to worry about the implementation of Ajax, but you only worry about your main tasks.

Comment: this should be a comment